# Saber se hora está correta

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um input onde é preenchido com horas (####:##), por exemplo: 1250:00, 0800:00, ...
Eu preciso saber se foi digitado corretamente e não 1250:66, 0800:99
Existe um máscara que não permite digitar letras ou espaços

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o evento `onblur` no input então basta usar `split` para dividir ambos números, feito isso o evento irá validar os valores e limpar o input se forem incorretos, por exemplo:

```js
var hora = document.getElementById("hora");

hora.addEventListener('blur', function () {
     var valores = this.value.split(':');

     if (!valores[0] || !valores[1]) return;

     var hora = valores[0];
     var minutos = valores[1];

     if (!/^(\d{2}|[1-9]\d+)$/.test(hora) || minutos > 59) {
         this.value = ''; //Apaga os valores do campo
     }
});
```

```html
<input id="hora" value="10:00">
```

Claro, que para as horas usei [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) para facilitar, ela funciona mais ou menos assim

```
 ^(\d{2}|[1-9]\d+)$
```

- `^` busca a expressão desde o começo
- `(` inicia um grupo, pois temos duas condições para a hora, com dois dígitos, que podem ser horas como 00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08 e 09
- `\d{2}` verifica se tem 2 digitos, se referindo aos números acima
- `|` depois do "pipe" (o sinal | se chama pipe) na regex verificamos se o numeros maiores que 09, então com o `[1-9]` checamos se a expressão começa com 1 até 9 para ser um valor valido
- `\d+` o sinal de mais diz a expressão que deve buscar numeros continuamente, até encontrar outra expressão, ou seja pode ter um ou mais numeros seguidos
- `)` finaliza o grupo, e termina assim ambas condições
- `$` "determina" que a expressão deve terminar exatamente ali, não podendo conter nada mais após o numero

Daria para fazer sem regex, mas ficaria um pouco maior o código.

---

Pode-se também tentar resolver tudo com regex, desde que ela não fique muito complexa para entender depois, ficaria algo como:

```js
var hora = document.getElementById("hora");

hora.addEventListener('blur', function () {
     if (!/^(\d{2}|[1-9]\d+):[0-5]\d$/.test(this.value)) {
         this.value = ''; //Apaga os valores do campo
     }
});
```

```html
<input id="hora" value="10:00">
```

Veja que agora só tem a regex, sem `split`, o que fiz foi adicionar `:[0-5]\d`, explicando:

- `:` é somente para checar o divisor entre a hora e os minutos
- `[0-5]` checa se o primeiro digito dos minutos não passam do 5, ou seja se digitar algo como `10:61` vai limpar o campo
- `\d` no final busca um numero, é equivalente a digitar `[0-9]`